# MS Office 2010/2007/2003 default font for default user

Tags: wix, installation, ms-office

I must create an installer which will change default font in MS Office (versions 2010, 2007 and 2003) for default user.

How can I accomplish this?

My first guess was to iterate over MS products and set registry key:
I have tried with registry key (ex. `...Office/14.0/(product ex. Word)/Options` with default font: `Arial,11`), but there was no effect.

After this I've tried to create folder Templates in `.../Default User/App Data/Microsoft/Templates/` and put there `Normal.dotm`. After creating new user - in his local App Data - this file was renamed to `NormalOld.dotm` and standard `Normal.dotm` file was created by MS Word.

How should I do this?

I'm using WIX installer so I can modify registry keys, copy files, and so on in installation process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. I've found solution:

**For MS Word**

1. Create `customNormal.dotm` (`cusotmNormal.dot` for 2007) - simply
   open new document, modify it as you wish and "Save as..." template ("ms word 97-2003
   template" for word 2003).
2. Put these files in `C:\Users\Default\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Templates` (in win 7 eng). In other Windows distrubutions seek in `Documents and Settings`, `Application Data`, and without `Roaming` in path.
3. Load deafult user hive in regedit on `HKU/<hive>`. Hive is in `C:\Users\Default\ntuser.dat` (hidden)
4. set in `HKU/[your hive name]/Software/Microsoft/Office/[11.0|12.0|14.0]/Word/Options` name: `GlobalDotName`, value: `customNormal.dotm`, type: `REG_SZ` if you have MS Word 2010 (14.0) or MS Word 2007 (12.0) and `customNormal.dot` for MS Word (11.0).
5. Unload the hive

**For MS PowerPoint**

1. Create `Blank.potx` (2010 and 2007) template just like for MS Word above and `Blank.pot` (2003)
2. Put these files in templates folder like in 2. for MS Word

**For MS Excel**

1. Create `book.xltx` (2010 and 2007) template just like for MS Word above and `book.xlt` (2003)
2. Put these files in `<templates folder>/../Excel/XLSTART`. For example: `C:/Users/Default/AppData/Roaming/Microsoft/Excel/XLSTART`

**EDIT**

And for **MS Outlook**

1. Open ms outlook. This will create file `NormalEmail.dotm` in your `templates folder`
2. Open this file (not **New** - default operation on double-click) `change styles->fonts->(your font)` and change it as you wish. Save it.
3. Put this file in default user `templates folder` for win 7: `C:\Users\Default\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Templates`

There is other solution for Normal.dotm MS Word 2010/2007 and for Outlook 2010 (that didn't work for me):
[Resolution for Normal.dotm and Outlook 2010](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/pl-PL/officesetupdeploy/thread/45af048b-3d8d-41c7-8373-d5a95dbcf48a)